# How can I get a counter to solve a sudoku puzzle?(python)

Tags: python, counter, sudoku

```
import os
from collections import counter

cwd = os.getcwd()
filename1 = cwd + "/sudoku1.txt"

grid1 = []
with open(filename1) as f:
    for line in f:
        grid1.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])


cwd = os.getcwd()

filename2 = cwd + "/sudoku2.txt"

grid2 = []
with open(filename2) as f:
    for line in f:
        grid2.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])

cwd = os.getcwd()

filename3 = cwd + "/sudoku3.txt"

grid3 = []
with open(filename3) as f:
    for line in f:
        grid3.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])




def allDifferent1D(l):
    for i in l:
        if i != 0:
            if l.count(i)>1:                    
                return False
    return True

def allDifferent2D(l):
    for row in l:
        if not allDifferent1D(row):
            return False
    for c in range(len(l)):
        col = []
        for r in range(len(l)):
            col.append(l[r][c])
        if not allDifferent1D(col):
            return False
    return True


def checkAll3By3s(grid):
    for i in [0,3,6]:
        for j in [0,3,6]:
            subGrid = [grid[i][j:j+3]]
            subGrid.append(grid[i+1][j:j+3])
            subGrid.append(grid[i+2][j:j+3])
            if not check3By3(subGrid):
                return False
    return True

def check3By3(grid):
    contains = dict()
    for i in range(0,10):
        contains[i] = False
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if contains[grid[i][j]]:
                return False
            else:
                contains[grid[i][j]] = True
    return True

def isValidSudoku(grid):
    # Check all rows and columns
    if (not allDifferent2D(grid)):
        return False
    if (not checkAll3By3s(grid)):
        return False

    return True

def complete(grid):
#checks the grid for any zeros or negatives. Takes priority over the sudoku checking aspect as it is implied to be invalid
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if grid[i][j]<=0:
                return False
    if (not allDifferent2D(grid)):
        return False
    if (not checkAll3By3s(grid)):
        return False


    return True



def compatableValue(grid,k):
    # creates a dictionary for each row/column that, for the purpose of this function, takes k and compares it with other values in the row/column, giving it a value of 1 if it is unique for the grid[i][j] value solveSudoku is iterating over 
    for i in range(len(grid)):
                seenValues=dict()
                for j in range(len(grid[i])):
                    a=collections.counter(grid[i][j])

                    if k != 0 and k in seenValues:
                        return False

                seenValues[k] += 1
                return seenValues[k]

def solveSudoku(grid):
#if the grid isnt a sudoku solution, the function sets out to fill in blank spaces(as pre filled in spots are the conditions for the grid and thus necessary

    if complete(grid)==True:
        return(grid)

    for i in range(0,9):
        for j in range(0,9):
            #only proceeds to change a value if it is zero. Calls compatableValue to see if each prospective value has been used
            if grid[i][j]==0:
                for k in range(1,10):
                    if compatableValue(grid,k)==1:
                        grid[i][j]=k
                        print(grid)
                    result=solveSudoku(grid)
                    if result != False:
                        solveSudoku(grid)
                #changes values back to zero for next attempt at solving the problem
                grid[i][j]=0
                return False
    return True




print(solveSudoku(grid2))
```

I am trying to solve the sudoku puzzle in which empty spaces are represented with zeros, and fill them in based on whether or not a counter has found them already in the row/column/3by3 grid. I am using python 3.4.1 and the counter does not work. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please edit and re-format your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `import` is:

```
from collections import counter
```

but then you try to use `collections.counter` instead.  You never imported `collections`, so that will be a `NameError` exception.  To fix it, change your `import` to

```
import collections
```

Also, as @DSM mentions in a comment, `Counter` must be spelled with an uppercase `C`.

I believe you have many other mistakes in that long, extremely repetitive code, for example you're trying to do `a=collections.counter(grid[i][j])` -- `counter` called with a number makes no sense (and will fail), and then you ignore `a` anyway, I believe.

But the number of bugs per question should be low, so by fixing one I think I've done my part for now:-)

Answer (score 1):

From the python docs:

```
c = Counter()                           # a new, empty counter
c = Counter('gallahad')                 # a new counter from an iterable
c = Counter({'red': 4, 'blue': 2})      # a new counter from a mapping
c = Counter(cats=4, dogs=8)             # a new counter from keyword args
```

Counter() returns a counter object, and you can pass it either nothing, an iterable, a mapping or multiple named amounts. The idea behind a counter object is that it will count how many times a value is added to it. Say, if I want to count fruits in a bowl, I can do things like:

```
bowl = Counter()
bowl['banana'] = 3
bowl['banana'] += 4
```

Now in your code, you seem to be passing the content of a single sudoku cell to the Counter's constructor. I'm not sure about what you're trying to do with the counter, but I don't think you need one in the first place. You're not even using the counter after its failed creation. And I don't understand what the seenValues dict is used for. Perhaps you should try writing what you're trying to do in English first so we can understand what you're trying to achieve.